# Spring data mongo query with not operator performance issue

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

We have query with not operator as below which cause for delay from mongodb side like 30s which cause performance impact

```
findByIdNotAndUserAndPrefixAndFileGroupId
```

But when we remove the `IdNot` as below, it does not cause any delay and return result with in 1s.

```
findByUserAndPrefixAndFileGroupId
```

In this case we would manually remove the id from return fetch list from code level

What is the reason for it? We use spring-data-mongodb-2.2.12 with Spring boot project

Comment: If I understand correctly, you didn't just change the "NOT" clause - you removed the ID from the query. If you try to findByIdAndUserAndPrefixAndFileGroupId, do you get the delay or not? It could be that the Id field is the root cause of the issue.